# Expected string or identifier, but <delimiter "/" at 8> found

Tags: php, symfony, exception, behat, mink

I have a Behat step like this, which asserts there is a link pointing to something with `/videos/` in the URL:

```
And I must see at least 1 "*[href~=/videos/]"
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
/**
 * Asserts that at least X amount of Y exist
 *
 * @Then /^I must see at least (?P<amount>\d+) "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iMustSeeAtLeast($amount, $selector)
{
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $container = $this->getContainer() ?: $session->getPage();

    $elements = $container->findAll('css', $selector);
    $actual = count($elements);
    AssertionAbstract::assertGreaterThanOrEqual(
        (int)$amount,
        (int)$actual,
        'Expected at least ' . $amount . ' of ' . $selector . ', found only ' . $actual . ' on ' . $session->getCurrentUrl() . '.'
    );
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException'
with message 'Expected string or identifier, but <delimiter "/" at 8> found.'
in vendor/symfony/css-selector/Exception/SyntaxErrorException.php:34
```

Why I can't put a slash in the step?

Comment: Did you try to escape your selector like "*[href~=\/videos\/]" ???

Comment: yup, try escaping like Paladin said

Comment: @Paladin it doesn't throw an error then but it doesn't find anymore elements matching (I find them when I put the selector in console in the browser `$("a[href*='\/artikel\/']")`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `*` in the front, `findAll` will find all the elements for the given selector.
Format your selector(s) like this:

```
[href~='/videos/']

a[href*='/artikel/']
```

As described in the Exception you are getting, it does't like the `/`, you need to add it in single/double quotes.

You can also try something like:

```
a[href*=artikel]
```

Comment: It does not make a difference if I use `a[href` or just `[href` and it does not make a difference if I use `*=` or `~=` - none of it works. `/` throws an error, `\/` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, if you have other special characters than a simple work you need to add it in single/double quotes.It throws error because `/` is not interpreted as part of the attribute value.